# Не срабатывает  "display: none"

Tags: javascript, css

```
 function(){$('h6').css('display','none')
```

Есть виджет для вставки комментариев на сайте.
тег h6 строит тоже он. 
Почему не срабатывает этот код? Ведь ДОМ-дерево уже сформировано. 
Теги , использованные за пределами виджета этим кодом скрываются.

Comment: Некоторые стили меняются, такие как шрифт размер  и т.п. 
Получается стоит запрет на некоторые стили?

Comment: Спрятал с помощью свойства opacity :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположу, что это виджет комментирования ala Вконтакте или Facebook? Тогда ничего у вас не получится: javascript с вашего домена не может как-либо воздействовать (даже прочитать) на содержимое iframe с другого домена. Прочитайте немного про [same origin policy](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Comment: в файрфоксе срабатывает. 
да, комментирование Вконтакте.

Comment: У вас не получится сменить стили внутри блока ВК, ибо это iframe